Why have I mark a string field as readonly in a immutable class if strings are immutable
I have an immutable class with only immutable properties. Strings are immutable so why I have to mark string field as readonly or use "init" in that class?
public class ImmutableType
{
    public readonly string LastName { get; }
}


The value of string objects cannot be changed, but variables/fields pointing to strings can. If you don't want that, use readonly.

Strings are immutable in a sense that you can't change a string object's value. That means all string manipulation code will result in a new string object.
Readonly fields or properties with init setter can be specified either via a constructor or via an object initializer. They are mainly used to capture "injected" data whose value should not be changed by the receiver object.
So, strings immutability is scoped only to the string object itself. Whereas readonly/init setter is scoped to an object's entire lifecycle.

The type System.String, or with the C# alias string, is a reference type. This means that a variable of such a type contains a reference (a memory address) to an object. Assuming that it was mutable, we could write:
string s = "hello";
string t = s;
s[1] = 'a'; // Not possible
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine(t);

Being a reference type means that after the second assignment both variables s and t are pointing to the same string object. Mutating the string assigned to s would also affect what you see through t. Therefore, this would print:
hallo
hallo

To avoid this misleading (and possibly unexpected and dangerous) behavior, strings are immutable. I.e., if you want to change "hello" to "hallo", you must create a new string. E.g., with:
s = s[0] + 'a' + s[2..]; // instead of s[1] = 'a';

Since a new string is assigned to s, this does not affect t which is still pointing to the original "hello" string object.

What you have is a getter only property and you can't mark a property with readonly. This one is readonly because it does not have a setter. You can mark fields as readonly.
What readonly does is to forbid an assignment to a field after the construction of the class. This leaves you with two ways to assign a readonly field or a getter only auto property a value:

Using an initializer: public string LastName { get; } = "Brown";
In the class constructor:
public class ImmutableType
{
    public ImmutableType()
    {
        LastName = "Brown"
    }

    public string LastName { get; }
    // Or as field
    public readonly string LastName;

    public void Change()
    {
        LastName = "Smith"; // NOT ALLOWED! (does not compile)
    }
}




Conclusion:

readonly restricts assigning a new string reference to a field.
String immutability forbids changes to the string object the property or field is referencing.


public readonly string LastName { get; } = "Brown"; doesn't compile, unless it's new and I'm way behind on the language version (always a possibility.)

@ScottHannen: yes, I was confused because the OP called his property a field.

Thanks for fixing the mix-up in my answer.

The code in your question doesn't compile because LastName is a property, not a field. You can't mark a property as readonly. But I understand the question.
If a string field or variable already contains a string and you assign a new one, you're not mutating an existing string. (You can't, because it's immutable, but that's not the point.) You're assigning a different string to that field.
This is easy to demonstrate with a unit test:
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        private string originalString = "original";

        [TestMethod]
        public void StringIsntChanged()
        {
            var copyOfOriginalString = this.originalString;
            this.originalString = "new";
            Assert.AreEqual("original", copyOfOriginalString);
        }
    }

If assigning the value "new" to originalString modified the string, the test wouldn't pass. But it does. The string "original" still exists, unchanged.
We can change the value of copyOfOriginalString:
copyOfOriginalString = copyOfOriginalString + "2";

...but we still haven't modified the string containing "original". We've just created a new string with the value "original2."
In that case, what happened to the first string containing "original"? Nothing. It's still there in memory. But now no variable or field references it, so it will get garbage collected.
It's the same as if we did:
var myList = new List<string> { "A" };
myList = new List<string>();

What happened to the first list containing "A"? Nothing. It's still there. Assigning a new list didn't modify the other one. The first list is now an object in memory that nothing references. It will be garbage collected.
As you can see this doesn't have anything to do with whether the object is mutable. A List<string> is. A string is not. But in each example we're giving the field or variable a reference to a new object, not modifying the existing object.
readonly doesn't mean "You can't modify the string." It describes the field, not the field's value. It means that after the object is created you can't set the field itself to refer to a different value.
That's an important distinction. If we don't realize that, we could declare a field like this:
readonly List<int> values = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3};

...and mistakenly think that the contents of the list can't change. But they can. You can add to the list, delete, or clear it. 'readonly` is about the field, not the list. It means that we can't set the field to a different list or to null.
